# Why can't I trigger select change event using C# WebBrowser control?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms

In the javascript I see the following defined:

```
 $('#dropDownId').change(function(){        
 ... do stuff...          
 });

 <select id="dropDownId">
     <option value="1">value 1</option>
     <option value="2">value 2</option>
     <option value="3">value 3</option>
 </select>
```

I've tried using the following code:

```
 webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("dropDownId").SetAttribute("value", "1");
 webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("dropDownId").Children[1].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
 webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("dropDownId").InvokeMember("onchange");
```

I can see the drop down get changed to the right value, but the following never gets executed:

```
 $('#dropDownId').change(function(){        
 ... do stuff...          
 });
```

Also, when I look at the properties for "dropDownId" in Chrome, the "onchange" event is null, so how can I invoke the above "change" script for the dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jquery` attaches events to allow for multiple event handlers, that's why `onchange` property of your `select` is null.

You can do:

```
function myChange(){        
 ... do stuff...          
}

<select id="dropDownId" onchange="myChange">
...
</select>
```

or

```
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("myChange");
```

or

```
function myChange_Jquery(){
  $("#dropDownId").change();
}

webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("myChange_Jquery");
```

Comment: Is there a way to invoke the jquery event?